# How do sibling NSManagedObjectContexts interact?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

If I have 3 NSManagedObjectContexts.

A. is the root context.

B. is a background saving context that generates NSManagedObjects after parsing a JSON

C. is a child context that is used in a NSFetchedResultsController

layout is like this

```
  A
 / \
B   C
```

When I make changes in B, i tell B to save, then I tell B.parent to save. My thoughts are that it would trigger C to send updates to my UITableView that its backing.

Is my theory correct? or is there something else I need to do to get C to see the updates from A. I am wanting the changes to pop into the tableview as they are made.

Specifically, I am trying to understand how these children respond to changes in their parent contexts and how this causes NSFetchedResultsController to trigger updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As saving only pushes changes one level up, the children of a managedObjectContext will get the changes made on their parent context only when you fetch again.

For more informations about how nested contexts work, checkout the video [What's New in Core Data for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=303) from the WWDC 2011.

Anyway, in your example, if A is writing and reading in/from the database, and B, why don't you make C a child of B? This way, saving C will also update the UI while saving B will push the changes and queue them for saving.

Comment: The problem with this is that my Sync is now dependent on the viewController and unless I am misunderstanding you, thats a bad idea. If I am wrong, could you please explain?

Comment: Nevermind, I got my letters backwards. My new question is, how would the Parent(B) notify C that there are new changes to pull? Is this automatic? Do I need to listen for this Notification?

Comment: No, it's not automatic. You should either listen for the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` sent by the parent or to observe it's `-hasChanges` property. If you choose to observe has changes, be careful not to touch the parent context, but to simply call `-executeFetchRequest:error:` on the child.

Comment: You can also tell C to automatically merge changes from parent. In swift `c.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true`. Then any change you make to B will be automatically pushed down to C. However, if you want to use B as a scratchpad (create an object you might delete later if the user cancels), C will pick up on those changes.